# Отправка POST запроса с пробелом в одном из параметров на языке C#

Tags: c#, post

Добрый день.
Встала задача отправки POST запроса на сайт с помощью C# и получения ответа в виде html.
Использую для этого следующий код:

```
    private static string POST(string Url, string Data)
{
  System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);
  req.Method = "POST";
  req.Timeout = 100000;
  req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  byte[] sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(Data);
  req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
  System.IO.Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
  sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
  sendStream.Close();
  System.Net.WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
  System.IO.Stream ReceiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
  System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
  //Кодировка указывается в зависимости от кодировки ответа сервера
  Char[] read = new Char[256];
  int count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
  string Out = String.Empty;
  while (count > 0)
  {
    String str = new String(read, 0, count);
    Out += str;
    count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
  }
  return Out;
}

string Answer = POST("http://testsite.ru/", "login=Andrey&password=pass word");
```

Проблема в том, что один из параметров POST-запроса может содержать пробел.
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно передать этот параметр?

Comment: Попробовал разные варианты настроек и выявил следующее поведение: при указании неправильной связки логи/пароль получаю в ответ html-код страницы с информацией о неправильном вводе логина или пароля. При этом, когда логин/пароль верны, то авторизация не происходит и я получаю в качестве ответа html-код страницы авторизации.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте использовать [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

```
"login=Andrey&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("pass word")
```

Comment: Функция HttpUtility.UrlEncode("pass word") преобразит строку "pass word" в строку "pass+word". Это мне не подойдет, т.к. при преобразовании в байты функцией Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(Data) "+" воспринимается, как "+", а не как пробел и авторизация не проходит.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте:

- [**Uri.EscapeUriString()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx) - чтобы экранировать только пробелы
- [**Uri.EscapeDataString()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) - чтобы экранировать всё (" ", "&", "=", "?" и др.)